# Parsing XML in Python all tags not showing up

Tags: python, xml

I am using the following code to parse XML:

```
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
    input = '''<collection shelf="New Arrivals">
    <movie title="Enemy Behind">
      <type>Wr, Thrller</type>
      <type> Wwwwar, Thrilllllller</type>   
      <format>DVD</format>
      <year>2003</year>
    </movie>
    <movie title="Transformers">
      <type>Anime, Science Fiction</type>
      <format>DVD</format>
      <year>1989</year>
    </movie>

   </collection>'''

   collection = ET.fromstring(input)
   lst = collection.findall('movie')
   print ('Movie count:', len(lst))
   for item in lst:
       print ('Movie Title', item.get("title"))

       typelst = collection.findall('movie')
       for item in typelst:
           print ('Type', item.find('type').text)
       print ('Format', item.find('format').text)
       print ('Year',item.find('year').text)
```

What i get as my output is:

```
Movie count: 2
Movie Title Enemy Behind
Type Wr, Thrller
Type Anime, Science Fiction
Format DVD
Year 1989
Movie Title Transformers
Type Wr, Thrller
Type Anime, Science Fiction
Format DVD
Year 1989
```

Notice how the Movie 1 has two 'Type'. Instead of displaying the two 'Type' for 'Movie' 1, I get the 'Type' of both 'Movie' 1 and 2.

I cant understand where the problem is in my for loop.

The desired output should be:
Movie count: 2

```
Movie Title Enemy Behind
Type Wr, Thrller
Type Wwwwar, Thrilllllller
Format DVD
Year 1989
Movie Title Transformers
Type Anime, Science Fiction
Format DVD
Year 1989
```

Comment: I also tried using 'print ('Type', item.findall('type').text)' but that gives me an error "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text' "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use 'findall' on the current item. That returns a list, so you need to loop over it.

```
collection = ET.fromstring(input)
lst = collection.findall('movie')
print ('Movie count:', len(lst))
for item in lst:
   print ('Movie Title', item.get("title"))

   movieTypes = item.findall('type')
   for movieType in movieTypes:
       print ('Type', movieType.text)
   print ('Format', item.find('format').text)
   print ('Year',item.find('year').text)
   print ""
```